# Adding Matrices in Matlab with out looping

Tags: matlab

how to sum m-by-n matrix A, to m by n by p matrix B, using Matlab without a For loop. Where the result C should be m by n by p matrix, the direct addition results in

Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

?

Comment: Can you specify **adding**. Do you want to *append* `A` to `B` or add `A` to `B` in all submatrices along the third dimension?

Comment: If you can do this as a for loop, then please post that code for clarity

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to add `A` to each of the `p` slices of `B` then you should use `bsxfun`:

```
bsxfun(@plus,A,B)
```

Answer (score 2):

First modify A to have the same size of B by replicating A, p times:

```
A = repmat(A ,[1 1 p]);
```

Now A is m by n by p the summation then can be done as

```
C = A + B
```

Where C is a m by n by p matrix

Comment: Hi @Nazer, just wanted to point out that in situations like this `bsxfun` is usually more efficient than `repmat`. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/